# Error connecting via SSH to VSI using Ansible in Schematics

Tags: ansible, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-schematics

I'm trying to connect to my Virtual Server Instance (VSI) on IBM Cloud using Ansible in Schematics. However, I'm encountering an error and unable to establish the SSH connection.
Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
ansible-playbook check | fatal: [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nUSER_NAME@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).", "unreachable": true}
ansible-playbook check | 
ansible-playbook check | PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ansible-playbook check | xxx.xxx.xx.xxx            : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0
```

I have confirmed that the SSH key is correctly associated with the VSI and I'm connected to the VSI on SSH from my local machine.

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue?
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message is clear: `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`. So the key you use **from ansible** is obviously not the one you used for your manual tests (which succeeded If I beleive your description). Please read the [ansible tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible): `... Installing Ansible and prerequisites, connection issues, ... are off-topic`. The other stackexchange site suited for this question is https://superuser.com

Comment: it the same key, but i dont know how can i check with schematics actions, and if there is a specific method to add my key.
i think the issue is not added correctly and i don't know how to do it with schematics actions.

do you have any idea about it ?